# Git user permissions for same user

Tags: git, gitolite

First I have `RW` access `repo-1`.

But after a system admin created `RW+ refs/tags`, now I am not able to push the content to `origin master`.

Is possible to get above two access for one user?

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try first the [`info` command](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/user#the-info-command) in order to confirm the list of repositories your Gitolite server allows you to access (run `ssh git@host info -h` for help)

Check if the gitolite admin can define [groups](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#group-definitions) (or possibly [roles](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/wild#roles)): that would allow one user to be registered in two different groups, allowing both pushing tags and branches.

Example:

```
repo foo bar

    RW+                     =   alice @teamleads
    -   master              =   dilbert @devteam
    -   refs/tags/v[0-9]    =   dilbert @devteam
    RW                      =   dilbert @devteam
    R                       =   @managers
```